# Generate warnings for incorrect sign with printf format specifier

Tags: c, gcc-warning

Is there any way to get gcc or clang to generate warnings for a mismatch with signed vs. unsigned variables with the printf() format specifiers?

I am aware of using `-Wformat`, however that only reports a warning if the size of the data type is incorrect.  It will not generate a warning if only the sign is incorrect.

For example the following does not generate a warning even though there is a mismatch with printing an unsigned int as signed:

```
uint32_t x = UINT_MAX;
printf("%d", x);
```

This will print out -1.

It seems like this would be a useful warning, but I haven't found any way to enable it.

Comment: Usually using a literal for `fmt` (the first argument) and cranking up warnings (`-Wall -Wextra`) does it for me with clang. I feel like GCC is hit-and-miss when it comes to printf hints but that's purely anecdotal.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I think asking from a compiler to perform a *function-specific* format string parsing is a bit too much, though it is already partially doing it (yeah, just because this specific function is a part of the standard...)

Comment: To print `stdint.h` types, use `inttypes.h` macros (that also includes `stdint.h`) to get the correct conversion type specifier!

Comment: " with printing an unsigned int " --> `uint32_t` is not necessarily an `unsigned int`.   Suggest `unsigned x = UINT_MAX;` to set aside that  issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use: `-Wformat` along with `-Wformat-signedness` (-Wformat must be present).

The latter warning option will warn if the argument is of incorrect signedness for the printf specifier.

gcc 6.2 will produce this warning: *warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'uint32_t {aka unsigned int}' [-Wformat=]*

Also `uint32_t x = UINT_MAX;` should be `uint32_t x = UINT32_MAX;`

Comment: Note: this is only supported in GCC 5.0 and later.

Answer (score 3):

As user 2501 correctly answered, `-Wformat` will enable the warnings for incorrect signess. But it does not necessary do it for using `"%u"` for an `uint32_t`, which is incorrect when you change the target to a system where `sizeof(int)<sizeof(uint32_t)`.

The correct format specifiers for `uint32_t` are `"%"PRIu32`, `"%"PRIx32`, `"%"PRIX32` and `"%"PRIo32`, with zero or more optional flags. However, this are macros that expand to a string. On one system with a 32 bit `int`, `"%"PRIu32"` is may expanded to `"%""u"`. On a other system a `int` is maybe only 16 bit long and `"%"PRIu32"` expands to `"%""lu"`. After the preprocesser, the compiler does not know if you wrote the format specifier by hand or if you used the indented macro. So the compiler does not generate a warning on a 32 bit system for using `"%u"` instead of `"%"PRIu32"`, but it will when you change the target architecture to one with a smaller `int` and you will have UB on this system when you ignore this warning.