# Why doesn't gcc emit a format warning?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>

void a(signed char a) {
    printf("%u\n", a);
}

void b(short b) {
    printf("%u\n", b);
}

void c(int c) {
    printf("%u\n", c);
}

void d(long d) {
    printf("%u\n", d);
}

void e(long long e) {
    printf("%u\n", e);
}

int main() {
    a(-1); //no warning
    b(-1); //no warning
    c(-1); //no warning
    d(-1); //warning
    e(-1); //warning
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested with gcc 11.2.0 using `gcc -std=c17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra test.c` and `g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra test.cpp`. Both don't give any warning to `a()`, `b()`, and `c()`. Is this intended, or a bug?

Comment: What kind of warning would you expect? That part is missing from your question...

Comment: What warnings are you expecting? What warnings are you actually getting? Don't assume everyone is using gcc.

Comment: Why should they? `-1` is an acceptable argument value for every function shown.

Comment: I think he's expecting a warning for using `%u` with a signed argument.

Comment: Values of types smaller than `int` get promoted to `int` for variadric functions, so what is being passed in a, b, and c is the right size.

Comment: Functions `a` and `b` are OK anyway, because all arguments can be promoted.

Comment: True, but `%u` would still be a mismatch for `int` values, promoted or otherwise. gcc has compile-time validation for `printf` parameters.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think they're expecting a warning about the `printf()` calls in the functions, not the calls to the functions.

Comment: @Barmar yes, MS VC does emit a warning for function `e` (without calling it at all) and so should gcc if you enable them.

Comment: @WeatherVane They're expecting a warning for all of them, since signed variables are being passed for a `%u` format, which expects an unsigned value.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Re "*%u would still be a mismatch for int values*", `-Wformat-signedness` would find that.

Comment: Note: with `...` arguments, `unsigned` and `int` are indistinguishable in the positive range.

Comment: @ikegami by default it is not enabled as it generates too many messages.

Comment: @ikegami I'd UV [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69993657/why-doesnt-gcc-emit-a-format-warning#comment123729832_69993657) as an answer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/40027508/2410359

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: C warnings are a mystery. Use `-Wformat-signedness` if you want warnings here.

Note that `-Wformat-signedness` requires `-Wformat`, which is already enabled by `-Wall`.

---

Apparently, the compiler only checks for sign mismatches when `-Wformat-signedness` is used. `-Wall` and `-Wextra` don't include `-Wformat-signedness`. I don't know why this is. Someone said it's because it would result in too many warnings, but that tells me it really needs to be used if it's such a common error!

So, all that's being checked are size mismatches. The two that warn (`d` and `e`) warn because a value of a type that's potentially larger than `int` is being passed. As for the other two, `signed char` and `short int` values are promoted to `int` values when passed to variadric (`...`) functions like `printf`, so `a` and `b` are equivalent to `c`.

Comment: No, all that’s being checked is correctness. `float` and `int` have same size usually yet the compiler warns you as it is not valid to reinterpret `float` as an `int`. (IIRC interpreting `long` as `int` is disallowed too *even if they have the same size).* But it is always allowed to reinterpret `int` as `unsigned int` (and vice versa).

Comment: @numzero The question isn't about compatibility of integer types with non-integer types, and neither is this answer. And no, "incorrectness" would be the wrong word to use. That would include sign-ness mismatch.

Comment: s/correctness/well-definedness/. Reading `int` via `unsigned*` is well-defined while reading it via `float*` (or even `long*` IIRC) is not, even if all these types have the same size.

Comment: @numzero Again, floats are off-topic. And so are pointers. We're taking about integers. Why do think I care about their size of non-integers.

Comment: Are you disagreeing that `printf("%d", 0L)` is UB while `printf("%d", 0u)` isn’t regardless of whether `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)`?

Comment: Oh, I guess you think I said there's no problem if `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)`? But I didn't say that.